# Add textbox data into a cell for the selected items in a listbox

Tags: for-loop, textbox, listbox

I have an excel file full of various data.  I have a listbox where the user can select items and move them to listbox2 (all from the same column in excel) which works.  Now I want to add the information from textbox8 (which is also on the same userform as the listbox) only for the selected items in listbox2.  Listbox2 contains serial numbers and textbox8 contains the user's initials.

The following throws a Compile error Method or data menber not found at the *** line below.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton6_Click()
   Dim LCount As Long
   For LCount = 0 to ListBox2.ListCount -1
   row_number = 3
   Do
     DoEvents
     row_number = row_number + 1
     item_in_review = Sheets("Rework").Range("E" & row_number)
     If item_in_review = ListBox2.Range("E" & row_number) Then   'Error line****
       'Adds the serial numbers to the list box
       Sheets("Rework").Range("M" & row_number) = TextBox8.Value
     End If
   Loop Until item_in_review = ""

 Next LCount
 End Sub
```